# Getting multiple lines in geom_line() time graph when used with another factor column to color in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to **color `geom_line()` time graph** based on **categorical values** of `Low, Med, High` from another column but it creates an issue by adding another line to the graph.

**Datset example:**

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India")
```

```
 Country.Region continent Date       Confirmed Deaths Case_Fatality_Ratio CFR_level
   <chr>          <fct>     <date>         <int>  <int>               <dbl> <fct>    
 1 India          Asia      2020-01-22         0      0                   0 Low      
 2 India          Asia      2020-01-23         0      0                   0 Low      
 3 India          Asia      2020-01-24         0      0                   0 Low      
 4 India          Asia      2020-01-25         0      0                   0 Low      
 5 India          Asia      2020-01-26         0      0                   0 Low      
 6 India          Asia      2020-01-27         0      0                   0 Low      
 7 India          Asia      2020-01-28         0      0                   0 Low      
 8 India          Asia      2020-01-29         0      0                   0 Low      
 9 India          Asia      2020-01-30         1      0                   0 Low      
10 India          Asia      2020-01-31         1      0                   0 Low      
11 India          Asia      2020-02-01         1      0                   0 Low      
12 India          Asia      2020-02-02         2      0                   0 Low      
13 India          Asia      2020-02-03         3      0                   0 Low      
14 India          Asia      2020-02-04         3      0                   0 Low      
15 India          Asia      2020-02-05         3      0                   0 Low
```

**Proportion of factors in column**

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "Italy") %>%
  select(CFR_level) %>% 
  table()

###### output #######

.
 Low  Med High 
  49  166  121
```

**Graph**

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, col = CFR_level)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**Issue**: I am getting two lines in this and unable to have just the desired 1 line.

**Cross checking:**

1. I have checked `duplication of dates` but seems like they are `unique`

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India") %>% 
  count(Date) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
```

> 0 rows

2. I have tried same graph with `geom_path()` but getting same results.
3. Tried graph with single color

```
grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `group = 1` in `aes` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

grouped_cases_df %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Confirmed, col = CFR_level, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks again @Ronak, this worked. I will accept the answer as soon as it let me accept it.